# Does "upgrading" to digital special edition for Hotline Miami 2 give you Jacket in Payday 2

Tags: payday-2, hotline-miami-2

So I already own Hotline Miami 2 but not the "digital special edition". In Payday 2 if you own the digital special edition you get Jacket as a playable character. If I just pay $5 to upgrade to digital special edition will I still get Jacket as a character?

Answer (score 2):

From [Overkills Website](http://www.overkillsoftware.com/games/hotlinemiami2/):

> Upon buying Hotline Miami 2: Wrong Number Digital Special Edition on Steam, you get the following:
>
> - Acquired when a player buys the Digital Special Edition of Hotline Miami 2: Wrong Number
> - Introduces 6 new Hotline Miami masks in PAYDAY 2
> - Adds 10 gallons of Hype Fuel to the Hype Train event
> - **Introduces Jacket of Hotline Miami fame as a playable character in PAYDAY 2**
> - Introduces an additional mask called “Richard Returns” in PAYDAY 2
> - Adds the Sociopath perk deck in PAYDAY 2
> - Adds the Carpenter’s Delight hammer melee weapon in PAYDAY 2
> - Adds Jacket’s Piece, a Submachine gun with accompanying weapon modifications in PAYDAY 2

The [Payday Wiki](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Jacket_Character_Pack) also says that:

> Requires "Hotline Miami 2: Wrong Number - Digital Special Edition" to be purchased on your Steam account.

Upgrading your copy would mean you have it on your steam account, and should unlock Jacket for you.  I've found nothing saying this doesn't work, and it wouldn't make sense for it not to.